# jQuery / Javascript Element height alway returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split some paragraphs into their respective line at each line break. My code seems to break when trying to recover the height of the element, it always returns '0'.

My function:

```
function getLines(element){
    words = element.text().split('');
    width = element.width();
    lines = [];
    hiddenElement = jQuery('<p width ="'+ width +'px", visible ="true"></p>');
    hiddenElement.text('i'); //add character to get height
    height = hiddenElement.height();
    alert(height);
    hiddenElement.empty();
    jQuery.each(words, function(i, val) {
      lineText = hiddenElement.text();
      hiddenElement.text(lineText + this);
        if(hiddenElement.height() > height) {
            lines.push(lineText);
            hiddenElement.text(this);
        }
   });
    alert(hiddenElement.height());
    alert(lines);
    jQuery('body').append(hiddenElement); // to see results
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQUhV/2/ - function called via `up arrow key`

Why does this return 0 rather than the height of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements have no dimension if they are not inserted into the document. Also, you are creating your `<p>` incorrectly.

Comment: Does this look like valid HTML to you? `<p width="20px", visible ="true"></p>`

Comment: He's suggesting you remove the comma between the width and visible

Comment: @ethorn10 Well, that and the fact that neither `width` nor `visible` are valid attribute names...

Comment: Ah yes, got mixed up between style attributes and html attributes.

Comment: Once you straighten that out, if you `.append` the `hiddenElement` to `element` prior to the `.height()` call, you should be fine.